# Pentaho Unable to access Remote Excel file

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I am using Pentaho 8.2. In one of my transformation step, I am trying to read an Excel file from a remote shared path on another server. However, I am encountering the following error:

```
ERROR (version 8.2.0.0-342, build 8.2.0.0-342 from 2018-11-14 10.30.55 by 
buildguy): Error processing row from Excel file 
[file://///shared/excel/test.XLSX]: 
org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\shared/excel/test.XLSX
```

I have checked the shared path and it is correct. I am getting this error only for Excel files; files in .csv and .txt format are working fine with the same file path.

Am I missing a .jar file or is there something else I should check?

Comment: Might the issue not be in another part of you path? for example the extention in uppercase? Doesn't seem to me that your missing a jar. Then you would not get an IO-error like this.

Comment: Seems like Pentaho cannot process remote .xlsx files. The only workaround that worked for me was to copy the .xlsx to the server where Pentaho is installed.

Comment: Pentaho (PDI) can easily handle excel files on other servers...